# Rate of change of resistance

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The voltage $V$ (volts), current $I$ (amperes), and resistance $R$ (ohms) of an electric circuit are related by the equation $V = IR$.

Suppose that $V$ is increasing at a rate of $3$ volt/sec while $I$ is decreasing at a rate of $-\frac{1}{4}$ amp/sec. Let $t$ denote time in seconds.

Determine the rate at which $R$ is changing when $V$ = 9 volts and $I$ = 5 amperes.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. You are supposed to show what you have tried and specify your difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

So you have $$V(t) = I(t) R(t).$$

1. Compute $V'(t)$ using product rule.
2. You are given $V'(t), I'(t)$ and $V,I$ are specified as well.
3. Plug into your result in (1) to compute what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$R(t)=\frac{V(t)}{I(t)} \implies R'(t) = \frac{V'(t)I(t)-V(t)I'(t)}{I(t)^2}.$$
You should get $R'(t) = \color{red}{\frac{69}{100}} \Omega/s$.

Answer (score 0):

We are given that
$$ V(t) = I(t) R(t). $$
Differentiating with respect to time, we get (via the product rule)
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t}(t) \cdot R(t) + I(t)\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t}(t). $$
Alternatively, in a more Newton-esque notation, this is
$$ V'(t) = I'(t)R(t) + I(t)R'(t).$$
Our goal is to find the rate at which $R$ is changing, i.e. to find $R'$.  Solving the above, we obtain
$$ R'(t) = \frac{V'(t) - I'(t)R(t)}{I(t)}. \tag{$\ast$}$$
All of the data on the right-hand side are given in the statement of the problem---it just requires a little interpretation.

We are told that voltage is increasing at a rate of 3 volts per second.  But this corresponds to an instantaneous rate of change, i.e. the derivative.  Therefore (suppressing units---this is not generally a good idea, but I am lazy)
$$ V'(t) = 3. $$
By similar reasoning, we have
$$ I'(t) = -\frac{1}{4}. $$

Finally, we are also told that
$$ V(t) = 9
\qquad\text{and that}\qquad
I(t) = 5. $$
From the first equation, this implies that
$$ R(t) = \frac{I(t)}{V(t)} = \frac{5}{9}. $$
Substituting all of these back into ($\ast$), we obtain
$$ R'(t) = \frac{V'(t) - I'(t)R(t)}{I(t)}
=\frac{3 + \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{5}{9}}{5}
= \frac{3\cdot 36 + 5}{5\cdot 36}
= \frac{113}{180}.$$